# BSE python: to pep or not to pep. Standards vs Readability

Tags: discussion, python

The [Blender Best Practices: Style Guide](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_best_practice.html#style-conventions) has a number of scripting recomendations, including the use of [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Quoting [PEP 8, beautiful code, and the tyranny of guidelines.](https://medium.com/@drb/pep-8-beautiful-code-and-the-tyranny-of-guidelines-f96499f5ac17#.artpax5rc)

> **Getting PEP 8'ed**
>
> Once a standard exists, there’s a great temptation to impose that standard on other people’s code arbitrarily. You might even believe you’re doing the world a favor.
>
> The PEP 8 standards warn against this with a quote from Ralph Waldo Emmerson: “*A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds*”. But that doesn’t stop eager PEP 8ers diving in and *complyifying* other developers’ code. Once we know how to do something — and we believe it’s useful and productive — we’ll be tempted to jump in and do it wherever we can. Thus once somebody knows how, they can’t help but perpetrate PEP 8.
>
> With any guideline: follow it yourself sooner than impose it on others.

Why?, later in the comments to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73699/15543) @David commented how readable the answer code is.  Agreed it is "*cobolically*" readable, **BUT** is a travesty against the [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) rules... the thin edge of the wedge ...

Just this small snippet produces the following [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) report.

```
for f in range(1,animLen + 1):
    S.frame_set( f ) # Set frame

    frmNum   = str( f ).zfill(3) # Formats 5 --> 005
    fileName = "angle_{a}_frm_{f}".format( a = angle, f = frmNum )
    fileName += S.render.file_extension
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = join( renderFolder, fileName )

# |2| 21: E201 whitespace after '('
# |2| 23: E202 whitespace before ')'
# |2| 25: E261 at least two spaces before inline comment
# |4| 15: E221 multiple spaces before operator
# |4| 24: E201 whitespace after '('
# |4| 26: E202 whitespace before ')'
# |4| 37: E261 at least two spaces before inline comment
# |5| 47: E201 whitespace after '('
# |5| 49: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
# |5| 51: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
# |5| 60: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
# |5| 62: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
# |5| 69: E202 whitespace before ')'
# |7| 50: E201 whitespace after '('
# |7| 73: E202 whitespace before ')'
```

The usage of `dislike( this )` has started to proliferate.  How do others feel about this.  Should some form of coding standard (pep8, tlousky2017, lol) be adhered to on BSE, or is it open slather?

Answer (score 3):

I think the effort required to globally enforce something like this will be much larger than any conceivable gain is worth:

- Lots of existing code which likely doesn't follow spec
- New users are arriving all the time; likely won't know (or care) about it
- As you say, code snippets don't have to be standardized to be understood.
- Being *understood* is the primary goal for most code snippets here; they usually are intended to demonstrate a concept rather than function as a complete implementation.

On the other hand, editing to improve *clarity, readability, and accuracy* is something which should always be advocated.   While enforcing an entire standard on a global level might not be very productive or practical, editing individual answers which you personally feel could be worded (or coded) in a clearer manner is absolutely something to encourage!

---

I personally `dislike( this )` as well ;)
<sub>But then again, I'm also the kind of person who's too lazy to write spaces in `their-css:rules;`.</sub>

Comment: *"With any guideline: follow it yourself sooner than impose it on others."*  is probably the go I suppose.  I'm certainly too lazy to bother pepifying others' code snippets